# URScript - how to get the actual TCP pose in tool space coordinate system?

Tags: control, robotic-arm, motion-planning, industrial-robot

I am writing a simple script for universal robots UR10 robotic arm.

I am trying to find a way to to see if the tool current position is outside of a 3D bounding box. the 3D bounding box is defined in the coordinate system of the tool. (y is up, x right, z backwards).

The `get_actual_tcp_pose()` function returns the tool pose in the 'base frame' coordinate system. it is my understanding that this is the coordinate system where the origin is at the base of the robotic arm.

So my questions are:

- How do I get the actual tcp pose in the TCP coordinate system (tool space)?
- Alternatively, how do I convert the pose returned by get_actual_tcp_pose() to the cooridnate system of the TCP using URScript?

Comment: Could You solve this problem? It would be very use for to know the solution.

Comment: as far as I remember, no. I used a different approach. The UR10 documentation is horrendous.

Answer (score 1):

The actual TCP pose in TCP coordinate system will always be [0,0,0,0,0,0] because the TCP Coordinate system is defined in the current tool orientation.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the translation vector of TCP between base (0,0,0), and you know the position of the box respect the base, you can be able to calculate if TCP is outside(inside the box by knowing the transformation matrix between base and TCP.

[image]